# Not displaying the country name (in 'Hindi' language)?

Tags: php, html

Not displaying the country name (in 'Hindi' language) in `<th></th>` tag?, but displaying country name in hindi in  tag correctly
Let me know the reason please
Iam using php

Comment: Care to explain more and give us some sample code of what you're doing?

Comment: Yup: could you be a bit more detailed and specific? The question doesn’t make any sense on its own at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add this meta tag inside the `head` element of your HTML, right before the `title` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```